# AssertWasCalled passes on unused variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

While refactoring unit tests in a project, I found some tests that should have been failing but were succeeding for some mysterious reason. After removing irrelevant code and moving everything into one method, the following minimal example still has the original behavior:

```
[Test]
public void TestThatShouldFail()
{
    // Arrange
    var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomething>();
    mock.Stub(wi => wi.SomeProperty).Return(MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomeProperty>());
    mock.SomeProperty.Stub(t => t.SomethingElse).Return(new SomethingElse());
    ...

    // Act      
    _foo.Foo();

    // Assert
    mock.AssertWasCalled(wi => wi.SomeProperty.DoSomething());
}
```

The variable `mock` is never passed, exposed or exported in any way which is available to the code running in the *Act* part. Still, the test passes, which should mean that the `DoSomething` method was called on the `SomeProperty` of the `mock` variable, which is obviously wrong.

How can this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above is already a result of some investigation, so it only contains the lines relevant to the problem and its solution.

The culprit is the last line of the *Arrange* part.

**As it turns out, the *Assert* line doesn't really check whether the `DoSomething` method was called on `SomeProperty`, but whether `SomeProperty` was accessed on `mock`!** And we actually did that in the last *Arrange* line, when stubbing a method on it.

I couldn't find any official documentation for it, so I can only assume that it considers only the first level of the expression in its argument, so **one shouldn't pass expressions with multiple levels of member access (dots) to `AssertWasCalled`** (or `AssertWasNotCalled`).

*(The proper way to check it would be `mock.SomeProperty.AssertWasCalled(wi => wi.DoSomething())`, but it wasn't needed here.)*